# Using Seaborn Catplot scatterplot creates a numerically unordered y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

Using [this dataset](https://github.com/bimmui/burner/blob/main/test.csv), I tried to make a categorical scatterplot with two mutation types (WES + RNA-Seq & WES) being shown on the x-axis and a small set of numerically ordered numbers spaced apart by a scale on the y-axis. Although I was able to get the x-axis the way I intended it to be, the y-axis instead used every single value in the Mutation Count column as a number on the y-axis. In addition to that, the axis is ordered from the descending order on the dataset, meaning it isn't numerically ordered either. How can I go about fixing these aspects of the graph?
The code and its output are shown below:

```
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.catplot(x="Sequencing Type", y="Mutation Count", hue="Sequencing Type", data=tets, height=16, aspect=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like your y values are strings

Comment: You can try `tets["Mutation Count"] = tets["Mutation Count"].astype(float)`.